# ASP.NET Core MVC - Add additional route parameters to existing URL without losing existing query params

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make offset-based pagination in my project, but I have encountered a problem. So I have a link to redirect users to a specific page based on page number (i - in this case):

`<a class="page-link" asp-route-pageNumber="@i"> @i </a>`

But the problem is that if I want first to filter my table e.g where for example **userStatus** is `ACTIVE` (1 in my case) and I have assigned a **tableSize** (to show only 5 rows) my URL would look like this:

`localhost:8080/users/?tableSize=5&userStatus=3`

Now if I want to go to the second page which is the same as the anchor link above the **URL** gets **overridden** and my **userStatus** and **tableSize** query parameters are gone and only **pageNumber** is there!

`localhost:8080/users/?pageNumber=2`

How can I make the link to only add the **pageNumber** to the existing URL as a query parameter and increment its value when I click another page number link and be like this:

`localhost:8080/users/?tableSize=5&userStatus=3&pageNumber=2`

I wouldn't like to use jQuery or JavaScript but if that is the only or better way feel free to share it!

I tried to use JavaScript to fire an on-click event when I click on a specific page number but that is not working properly, because every time I am clicking the link the function is adding another pageNumber parameter to the URL, and if I check the URL first if pageNumber exists then the value of query param would be a mess to replace it.

Comment: @mxmissile - what do you mean by the second case? I put the anchor link in a for loop to show all pagination numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4.  `@i` shows the number of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your current url is `localhost:8080/xxx/?tableSize=5&userStatus=3`,and you want to add the value of `tableSize` and `userStatus` to `<a class="page-link" asp-route-pageNumber="@i"> @i </a>`.You can try the following code:

```
@{
    string tableSize= Context.Request.Query["tableSize"].ToString();
    string userStatus= Context.Request.Query["userStatus"].ToString();
}
<a class="page-link" asp-route-pageNumber="@i" asp-route-tableSize=@tableSize asp-route-userStatus=@userStatus> @i </a>
```